# SQL append distinct values from two columns and two tables

Tags: sql, append

I'm trying to create SQL code that takes the distinct values from two columns and “appends” them. By that, I mean that that the following table:

```
Account   Article
-----------------
   1        1
   1        2
   2        3
```

Should produce the following result:

```
Account   Article
-----------------
   1        1
   1        2
   1        3
   2        1
   2        2
   2        3
```

I'm doing this from two tables using a union, so the idea is to get all combination of all unique account numbers in both tables with all unique article numbers in both tables. And I want a clause that limits both tables to a order date later then one year ago.

So far I have:

```
Select Distinct 
    "Tra.".cus_outnum As "account number", 
    "Tra.".artnum As "article number"
From 
    (table1) "Tra." 
Where 
    "Tra.".invdat >= DATEADD(year, -1, GETDATE())

Union

Select Distinct 
    "Sal.".outnum As "account number", 
    "Sal.".artnum As "article number"
From 
    (table2) "Sal."  
Where 
    "Sal.".deldat>= DATEADD(year, -1, GETDATE())
```

Problem is that it only gives me the combination where both account and article exist. I have unsuccessfully tired to do it with a with statement:

```
WITH temp1 AS 
(
     Select distinct cus_outnum 
     From table1
), temp2 AS
(
     Select distinct artnum 
     From table1
)
SELECT cus_outnum,artnum
FROM temp1, temp2, table1
```

Ant help would be much obliged!

Comment: Tag the DBMS (i.e. `MySQL`, `SQL Server`, etc..) that you are using.

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 25 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This gives the expected result:

```
with cte1 as (Select distinct account from test)
,cte2 as (Select distinct article from test)
Select * from cte1 cross join cte2
```

Schema:

```
Create table test(account int, article int);
Insert into test values(1,1);
Insert into test values(1,2);
Insert into test values(2,3);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need `cross` join :

```
select distinct t.Account, t1.Article
from table1 t cross join
     (select distinct article from table) t1;
```