# SQL add max and second max date to query that includes with

Tags: sql

Posted a question yesterday about [SQL append distinct values from two columns and two tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51029389/sql-append-distinct-values-from-two-columns-and-two-tables?noredirect=1#comment89054335_51029389) that resulted in the following code:

```
with cte1 as 
(Select Distinct "Tra.".cus_outnum As "account number" from table1 "Tra." Where "Tra.".invdat >= DATEADD(year, -1, GETDATE())

union

Select Distinct  "Sal.".outnum As "account number" From table2 "Sal."  Where "Sal.".deldat>= DATEADD(year, -1, GETDATE()))
,cte2 as
(Select Distinct "Tra.".artnum As "article number" from tabel1 “Tra.” Where "Tra.".invdat >= DATEADD(year, -1, GETDATE())

union

Select Distinct ISNULL("Sal.".org_artnum, "Sal.".artnum) As "article number" From table2 "Sal." Where "Sal.".deldat>= DATEADD(year, -1, GETDATE()))

Select * from cte1 cross join cte2
```

It produces a table with all distinct combination of account numbers and article numbers from two different tables where orders are done later than one year ago.

Next object that I'm struggling with is to include the latest and second latest purchase date in two new columns.  If no purchase is done for any combination of account and article, it should result in a null(blank) value. And the latest/second latest date (i.e max date) should come from either one or the other of the tables. End result should be along the lines of:

```html
<table><tbody><tr><th>Account</th><th>Article</th><th>Latest Date</th><th>Second to latest Date</th></tr><tr><td>1</td><td>1</td><td>26.06.2018</td><td>13.03.2018</td></tr><tr><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>15.05.2018</td><td>Blank (no purchase)</td></tr><tr><td>2</td><td>1</td><td>23.06.2018</td><td>30.06.2017</td></tr><tr><td>2</td><td>2</td><td>Blank (no purchase)</td><td>Blank (no purchase)</td></tr></tbody></table>
```

Many thanks for all the help, it is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Partially pseudeo. To get more detailed help please offer a [db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/).

```
SELECT
    a.Account as Account,
    b.Article as Article,
    (<SUBSELECT> MAX(DATE) FROM ... WHERE ... ) as LatestDate,
    (<SUBSELECT> MAX(DATE) FROM ... WHERE ... < LatestDate ) as 'SecondToLatestDate')

FROM
    accounts a JOIN articles b

+ some IFNULL's
```